# How does double bracket parameter work in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parameters

In some D3 examples, I saw a double bracket expression as a parameter.

Like below code,

```
d3.contours().size([grid.n, grid.m]).thresholds(thresholds)(grid).map(transform);
```

I thought the `.thresholds()` method binds 2 parameters, `thresholds` and `grid` which are in brackets.

If this expression is a shortened format, what method is omitted between those brackets?

Comment: That has nothing to do with D3, that's just JavaScript. `a()()` is just a function that returns another function, which you can call again (with or without arguments). I just added the tag [tag:javascript], so someone can find the adequate duplicate target.

Comment: As Gerardo said, but to clarify a little.  `thresholds(thresholds)` returns a function and you're calling that function immediately with `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

This question had previously been closed as being a duplicate of [*"What is 'Currying'?"*](/q/36314). Although it technically might be interpreted as a case of currying I, personally, think this interpretation is totally missing the point of how it's done the D3-way. I re-opened the question because I think it is worthwile describing it in D3's own terminology.

Various D3 modules know a concept of **generators**—not to be confused with JavaScript's own [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) which were introduced to the standard with ES6—that are used to create some sort of SVG data representing the data passed to the generator. In your case, [`d3.contours()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour#contours) returns the contour generator from the [d3-contour](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour) module. Other well-known examples are the generators from the [d3-shape](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape) module that create various types of shapes for lines and paths to be used in the resulting SVG. These *generators* are constructed by functions that in terms of D3 are sometimes referred to as *factories*. In your code that factory is

```
d3.contours()   // factory returning a countour generator object
```

The resulting generator has a default configuration determining its standard behavior which can be re-configured by calling methods on the generator object. Because all those methods return the generator object they were called upon they facilitate method chaining that is often seen in D3 code:

```
d3.contours()  
  // The next two lines are used to configure the generator. 
  .size([grid.n, grid.m])
  .thresholds(thresholds);
```

Since the last of those calls—in your case `.thresholds(thresholds)`—does also return the generator the whole expression evalutes to the newly created and configured generator object. Quite often, you will see the reference to that object being stored in some field for purposes of clarity and re-use.

```
const contourGenerator = d3.contours()  
  .size([grid.n, grid.m])
  .thresholds(thresholds);
```

The resulting generator can then be [called](https://github.com/d3/d3-contour#_contours) passing in the data, i.e. `grid` in your case, and will return the transformed data that can be used to build the SVG:

> Computes the contours for the given array of *values*, returning an array

Given the information above, it is easy to see that the following two statements are basically equivalent:

```
// 1. call the generator by the stored reference
const contourArray = contourGenerator(grid);

// 2. call the generator directly on the evaluated expression
const contourArray = d3.contours().size([grid.n, grid.m]).thresholds(thresholds) (grid);
//                   ^---------------evaluates to the generator----------------^
```

Just to round things up, the following call to `.map()` could be implemented for either of the above approaches as it is just the standard mapping function called on the resulting array that is returned from the generator. Verbosely, your code could be rewritten as:

```
const contourGenerator = d3.contours()  
  .size([grid.n, grid.m])
  .thresholds(thresholds);

const contourArray = contourGenerator(grid);

const mappedArray = contourArray.map(transform);
```